# seriesmarks is not visible for specified valueindex in teechart2017

Tags: visual-c++, teechart

In VS2013,teechart2017.ocx,

1. I make a dialog based MFC project.
2. I add a teechart on the dialog, changed the property of mark to
   display value,set drawevery to 1,visible,not autoposition.
3. I used getserismark event to display only specified marks.
4. I add 20000 point in series0,
5. if i used teechart8, it display correctly,but for teechart2017,the
   marks disappeared for all.

   ```
   void CMFCApplication2Dlg::OnGetSeriesMarkTchart1(long SeriesIndex, long ValueIndex, BSTR* MarkText)
      {
          // TODO:  
          if (B_Filter)
           {
           if ((ValueIndex == 1250) || (ValueIndex == 137)|| (ValueIndex == 10000))
           {

           }
           else
           {
           m_Chart1.Series(SeriesIndex).GetMarks().GetItem(ValueIndex).SetVisible(false);
           }
      }
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've reproduced the problem ([#1986](http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=1986)) and I've added the `CalcVisiblePoints` property for the next maintenance release.

There was an optimization introduced in v2016.0.0.1 that is causing this issue. You have to set `TChart1.Series(0).CalcVisiblePoints = False` to skip that optimization and make it work as in v8.

With the new v2018.0.2.9 you can do this:

```
#include "CAspect.h"
#include "CLegend.h"
#include "CSeries.h"
#include "TeeChartDefines.h"
#include "CMarks.h"
#include "CMarksItem.h"

//...

    CAspect a = mChart1.get_Aspect();
    a.put_View3D(false);

    CLegend l = mChart1.get_Legend();
    l.put_Visible(false);

    mChart1.AddSeries(scFastLine);
    CSeries s = mChart1.Series(0);
    s.FillSampleValues(20000);
    CMarks sm = s.get_Marks();
    sm.put_Visible(true);

    for (int i = 0; i < s.get_Count(); i++) {
        CMarksItem smi = sm.get_Item(i);
        smi.put_Visible((i == 1250) || (i == 137) || (i == 10000));
    }

    s.put_CalcVisiblePoints(false);
```

Comment: Hello Yeray,wether it is added in teechart2018.0.2.9. and how to change this property in VC++ in vs2013.

Comment: 1.I download the teechart2018.0.9 and install.2.I added "m_Chart1.Series(0).SetCalcVisiblePoints(FALSE);" in my code.3.run the program, it will display"can not find member"

Comment: Please send a mail to "info at steema dot com", providing your license details and referencing this thread and we'll send you a test ocx